# Непонятные undefined

Tags: javascript

Есть строка

```
const s = 'Давно выяснено, что при <colored>оценке</colored> дизайна и <tooltip>композиции читаемый</tooltip> текст мешает'
```

Нужно разбить ее на части, где разделителем являются теги и их содержимое. Написал регулярку, разбил но в результирующем массиве появились непонятные `undefined` от куда они, как исправить регулярку что бы их не было ?

```js
const s = 'Давно выяснено, что при <colored>оценке</colored> дизайна и <tooltip>композиции читаемый</tooltip> текст мешает'
console.log(s.split(/\s*(<colored\s*.*>.*<\/colored>)\s*|\s*(<tooltip\s*.*>.*<\/tooltip>)\s*/));
```

Comment: регулярку бы сократить до `/(<(colored|tooltip)>.*?<\/\2>)/`, но там вторая группа мешает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undefined` происходит от того, что все группы в скобках должны добавить в массив своё соответствие. У вас каждый раз при выборе из возможных вариантов (символ `|`) одна пара имеет соответствие, а другая нет, она-то и производит `undefined`.

Вместо скобок, чтобы сохранить разделители, можно использовать загляднывание вперёд и назад нулевой длины. При них, правда, станут мешать опциональные пробелы по бокам тегов, они произведут дополнительные элементы массива с пробелами. Поэтому их можно убрать из регулярки и заменить на обработку элементов при помощи `trim()`:

```js
const s = 'Давно выяснено, что при <colored>оценке</colored> дизайна и <tooltip>композиции читаемый</tooltip> текст мешает'
console.log(
  s.split(/(?=<colored\b.*?>.*?<\/colored>|<tooltip\b.*?>.*?<\/tooltip>)|(?<=<colored\b.*?>.*?<\/colored>|<tooltip\b.*?>.*?<\/tooltip>)/)
   .map(substring => substring.trim())
);
```

Однако некоторые старые браузеры и Safari не поддерживают заглядывание назад, так что проверяйте ваш целевой диапазон:

https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind